# Error Message in Plotly (in R) about "markers"

Tags: r, plotly

Chunk of code...

```
library(plotly)
library(tidyverse)

my_fav_graph_SO <- function(my_df, my_levels) 
{

  x_axis <- list(
    title = "Variable Name",
    range = my_levels)

  primary_y_axis <- list(
   title = "coeff")

    p <- plot_ly() %>%

    add_lines(x = ~ my_df$factor_level,
              y = ~ my_df$coeff,
              yaxis = primary_y_axis,
              marker = list(color = "blue")) %>%

    layout(
      title = "graph",
      xaxis = x_axis,
      yaxis = primary_y_axis)

  p
}

df <- data.frame(factor_level = c("Aries", "Taurus", "Gemini", "Cancer", "Leo", "Virgo", "Libra", "Scorpio", "Sagittarius", "Capricorn", "Aquarius", "Pisces"),
                 exposure = c(50, 70, NA, 40, 45, 78, 42, 22, 28, 49, 50, 31),
                 coeff = c(1.1, 1.2, NA, 1.3, 1.8, 1.6, 1.4, 1.3, 1.2, 1.1, 1.5, 1.3))

my_levels = c("Aries", "Taurus", "Gemini", "Cancer", "Leo", "Virgo", "Libra", "Scorpio", "Sagittarius", "Capricorn", "Aquarius", "Pisces")

df$factor_level <- factor(df$factor_level, levels = my_levels)

my_fav_graph_SO(df, my_levels)
```

The graph draws ok but I'm getting a warning:

> A marker object has been specified, but markers is not in the mode
>
> Adding markers to the mode...

Can anyone advise how to get rid of this warning pls? I'm unsure what I've done wrong.

Thanks.

Comment: not able to answer but maybe [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51966920/issue-changing-marker-color-in-r-plotly-scatter-plot) will give you a hint

Comment: Please see my answer below - old question and SO won't notify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are adding a line trace via `add_lines` but specifing a marker color via `marker = list(color = "blue")`. Changing `marker` to `line` let's you get rid of the warning:

```
library(plotly)
library(tidyverse)

my_fav_graph_SO <- function(my_df, my_levels) 
{

  x_axis <- list(
    title = "Variable Name",
    range = my_levels)

  primary_y_axis <- list(
    title = "coeff")

  p <- plot_ly() %>%

    add_lines(x = ~ my_df$factor_level,
              y = ~ my_df$coeff,
              yaxis = primary_y_axis,
              line = list(color = "blue")) %>%

    layout(
      title = "graph",
      xaxis = x_axis,
      yaxis = primary_y_axis)

  p
}

df <- data.frame(factor_level = c("Aries", "Taurus", "Gemini", "Cancer", "Leo", "Virgo", "Libra", "Scorpio", "Sagittarius", "Capricorn", "Aquarius", "Pisces"),
                 exposure = c(50, 70, NA, 40, 45, 78, 42, 22, 28, 49, 50, 31),
                 coeff = c(1.1, 1.2, NA, 1.3, 1.8, 1.6, 1.4, 1.3, 1.2, 1.1, 1.5, 1.3))

my_levels = c("Aries", "Taurus", "Gemini", "Cancer", "Leo", "Virgo", "Libra", "Scorpio", "Sagittarius", "Capricorn", "Aquarius", "Pisces")

df$factor_level <- factor(df$factor_level, levels = my_levels)

my_fav_graph_SO(df, my_levels)
```